# Mixed content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, mixed-content

In this [login page](https://make-it-happen.it/login), when someone click on the "Accedi" button, the login_user.php file is called. The call happens via `$.post()` JQuery methods.

This is the call:

```
username = $('#username').val();
password = $('#password').val();

$.post("./function/login_student.php", {
        username:username,
        password:password
    },
    function (data){ 
        var array = $.parseJSON(data);

        if(array.error == "1" || array.not_present == "1"){
            $('#alertLogin').addClass('alert-danger').text('Ti preghiamo di controllare i campi').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
        }
        else if(array.not_active == "1"){
            $('#alertLogin').addClass('alert-danger').text('Ti preghiamo di verificare il tuo account').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
        }
        else{
            let username_studente = array.username_studente;
            $(location).attr('href','student.php?username=' + username_studente);
        }
    }
);
```

When I seen the error, I suppose that the problem was the url, but I tried also with this url `https://www.make-it-happen.it/function/login_student.php` but the problem persists

### UPDATE

The problem was this code for remove the php extension file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

How can I fix the problem in such a way that the extension is hidden and there is no problem with the `Mixed content`?

Comment: If you look at your network tab you will see that when you click the button it is being redirected to `http://www.make-it-happen.it/login` .  Your server is telling the client to redirect to an http page.

Comment: @Taplar I update the post! Do you have same suggestion?